# Shortcut with electron desktop app suddenly stopped appearing

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm using `electron-packager` for creating packages and `electron-squirrel-startup` for creating the installer. It was working fine, I was getting shortcut icon and everything was fine. But all of sudden now it stopped working. No shortcut icon, and even in task manager its showing `"Electron"` instead of `"MyApp"`. I'm clueless at this moment.

Package command:

```
"package": "electron-packager . MyApp --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --overwrite --asar=true --force --icon=myApp.ico --version-string.ProductName=myApp --version-string.CompanyName=\"My Tech Solutions\"",
```

And the `electron-squirrel-startup` code is:

```
var electronInstaller = require('electron-winstaller');

resultPromise = electronInstaller.createWindowsInstaller({
    appDirectory: '\MyApp-win32-ia32',
    outputDirectory: 'C:/release32',
    loadingGif: './loader.gif',
    authors: 'My Tech Solution.',
    exe: 'MyApp.exe',
    description: 'My Business Accounting App',
    certificateFile: './Cert/Mycert.pfx',
    certificatePassword: '******',
    setupIcon: './myApp.ico',
    iconUrl: 'https://myapp.in/favicon/favicon.ico',
    setupExe: 'myApp.exe',
    noMsi: true,
    remoteReleases: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vyapardesktop/desktop/',

});

resultPromise.then(() => console.log("It worked!"), (e) => console.log(`No dice: ${e.message}`));
```

Comment: Thank you Mike Wood for such beautiful edit. You're great. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you installed the newest version of `electron-packager` that now doesn't have an option for `version-string`, they changed it to `win32metadata`.

From what I've seen `win32metadata` option is exactly like `version-string` except it's name is different.

Your package script would become this:

```
"package": "electron-packager . MyApp --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --overwrite --asar=true --force --icon=myApp.ico --win32metadata.ProductName=myApp --win32metadata.CompanyName=\"My Tech Solutions\"",
```

[`win32metadata`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#win32metadata) in documentation

Comment: Thanks a ton. I will have a look at this. But to my surprise its proper now. The icon started appearing properly and everything is fine. I wonder what can be the reason. And thanks a lot for that edit. Have always seen people criticizing about grammar and stuff but you helped me improve. Thank you..

Comment: No problem @ishwarrimal, happy to help :)